# How to find whether the MSI has InstanceTransforms enabled or not?

Tags: wix, multiple-instances, wix3.7

We have an WPF based external UI application i.e setup.exe which wraps the msi's developed in WiX. We have a requirement that some components/msi's requires multiple instance support and some don't require multiple instance support but all components are part of single package.

We pre-defined InstanceID's, ProductCode and UpdgradeCode for each instances during build time. Because creating instance ID on the fly create complexity in the patch/upgrade scenarios.

We want Setup.exe to do 2 things,

## 1. It should lookup the target computer and detect if any component is installed already. To do that Product code required.

## 2. It should automatically detect the msi's copied into the path and lookup the InstanceTransforms exist or not in the msi. If InstanceTransforms found then it should fetch the Instance ID's defined. Because we don't want to keep any business logic in Setup.exe. Reason is to avoid recompile Setup.exe every time we change the msi.

Now Setup.exe will know whether the msi requires instance ID or not based on that it will invoke the msi and pass commandline parameters. It's kind of plugin mechanism to avoid regression.

Issue:
We could not retrieve the InstanceTransforms from MSI maybe because it's not a property. We have checked the _Storages table and property table but we could not figure it out.

How can we retrieve the InstanceTransforms element and it's Instance definition (InstanceID and ProductCode) in the msi?

Please advise.

@Christopher Painter

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow your question exactly.  In general you can use the WiX DTF Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller library to do queries against the MSI database and MSI API.   You can query the Property table to get the ProductCode then query installed products to see if it's installed.  To see if the MSI has embedded transforms available you can query the _Storages stream, apply the transform and then read the properties for those also.

I'm adept at WPF/MVVM development if you want to hit me up for more detailed consulting.

Comment: I have an MSI with 50 embedded transform instances inside. I know the Instance's Id for each instance. Is it possible for me to get the product code for a given Id from the MSI?

Comment: Yes. Open the database. Apply the transform. Query the value and close the database.  Just like you would in ORCA but do it in DTF.

Comment: I have a logic that if _Storage table has records i.e >0 then I can conclude that MSI has embedded Transforms, if it returns 0 then no embedded transform. Is that correct? or any other efficient way to determine whether msi has embedded transform or not?